# Excepción de tipo NullPointerException en java

Tags: java

El siguiente código genera este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?

```
import java.io.*;

public class While {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Console console = System.console();

         String anyQuestions = console.readLine("Are there any questions?  ");
          while (anyQuestions.equals("yes")) {
              String question = console.readLine("What is your question?  ");
              console.printf("I do not understand:  %s", question);
              anyQuestions = console.readLine("Are there any more questions  %n");
        }
        console.printf("Next slide...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Abre una consola (cmd, terminal, etc). Compila tu programa con `javac While.java`. Luego que termine se generará el compilado y ejecuta `java While` para que veas cómo funciona el programa.

Answer (score 1):

La causa de este error es por el uso de IDE (asumo que va ser Eclipse). `System.console()` te da una consola **solamente** si hay una conectada a la maquina virtual (que hay por ejemplo si tu arrancas tu programa usando `java <clase>` (en tu caso `java While`).

En el caso de eclipse por ejemplo el "Run as Java" arranca el programa en un proceso, así en este proceso no existe ninguna consola conectado y `System.console()` devuelve `null`.

Si tu programa esta diseñado de correr desde una consola o un terminal, deberías seguir usando la consola pero quizas agregar una alternativa, comprobando si **tienes** consola:

```
import java.io.*;

public class While {

    private static Console consola = null;
    private static Scanner sc = null;

    private void getInput(){
        consola = System.console();
        if (consola == null) sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    private String readLine(String text){
        if (consola!=null) return consola.readLine(text);
        System.out.println(text);
        return sc.nextLine();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getInput();

         String anyQuestions = readLine("Are there any questions?  ");
          while (anyQuestions.equals("yes")) {
              String question = readLine("What is your question?  ");
              System.out.println(String.format("I do not understand:  %s", question));
              anyQuestions = readLine("Are there any more questions? ");
        }
        System.out.println("Next slide...");
        if (sc!=null) sc.close();
    }
}
```

Así tu código usa la consola si hay, y `Scanner` en el caso que no hay.

Answer (score -1):

Por qué no utilizas la clase Scanner?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Are there any questions? ");
            String anyQuestions = sc.next();

            while (anyQuestions.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("What is your question?");
                String question = sc.next();
                System.out.println("I do not understand: " + question);

                System.out.println("Are there any more questions");
                anyQuestions = sc.next();
            }
            System.out.println("Next Slide...");
        }
```

Comment: GRACIAS! Funciona mejor que console! Voy a seguir usando scanner.

Comment: Por alguna raxon tengo un error en                                                console.printf("I do not understand:  %s", question);

Comment: Reemplazalo con eso: `System.out.println("I do not understand: " + question);`

Comment: @MarioGomez mantén el código que tienes con `Console` pero ejecuta tu programa en un terminal o consola y allí verás los resultados.

Answer (score -1):

Al usar `System.console` en un IDE siempre retornará null, deberar correr el archivo Java desde la consola de comando si es que necesitas ver los resultados.

AL igual podrias usar la clas `Scanner`

```
 //importas tu clase scanner
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class While {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String respuesta;

//instanciamos la clase escanner para poder leer
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//mandamos un mensaje al usuario
System.out.println("Are there any questions?");
//leemos la respuesta
respuesta = scanner.nextLine();

while (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
  System.out.println("What is your question?  ");
  //leemos la respuesta
  String question = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println("I do not understand:  %s", question);
  //mandamos un mensaje al usuario
  System.out.println("Are there any questions?");
  //leemos la respuesta
  respuesta = scanner.nextLine();
}


  scanner.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Gracias Miguel! Voy a seguir usando el la clase scanner!

Comment: "Al usar System.console en un IDE siempre retornará null" mientras que esta es la causa del NPE, existen maneras de cambiar esto en el IDE o bastaría con ejecutar la aplicación desde cmd o un terminal. No es necesario usar Scanner.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 1.- como podras leer bien ahi dice y cito "AL igual podrias usar la clas Scanner", 2.- "deberás correr el archivo Java desde la consola de comando si es que necesitas ver los resultados.". ahi explico que debe ejecutarlo desde una terminal y doy como consejo usar la clase Scanner mas no obligo a utilizarla

Comment: Claro, y por eso el resto de tu respuesta consiste en convertir el código del OP con el uso de `Scanner`...

Comment: Bueno para que desgastarme, gracias por la retroalimentación.